# I am to store the length of an array but when the submit button is clicked I use array.splice so the length of the array goes down?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using array.splice every time a user answers a question that question is taken out of the array.

At the end of the quiz I call a function which contains `score + '/' + array.length +`

As a result to useing splice and this function being called at the end of the quiz the `array.length` is undefined as all questions have been splied.

How can I store the length of the array at the start and keep the same array.length the same to use at the end of the quiz?

```
function displyResult () {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Your score was ' + score + '/' + array.length + 'correct!!!';
}
```

I can do it using an if statement but this seems wrong to me there must be an easier way?

The result I get is:

> Your score was 1/undefined correct!!!

It should just display the length of the original array before being sliced

Comment: `var originalLength = array.length;` before the rest of the code?

Comment: You could store the initial length in a variable to reference at the end of the quiz.

Comment: @ Aurel Bílý, yepp thats what it was I had it to low down in code so it was getting reset every time. Thanks  : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible to store the length `array.length` to a variable Like `var length = array.length` and check if it is not undefined.

```
using length = array.length ? array.length : 0;

function displyResult () {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Your score was ' + score + '/' + length + 'correct!!!';
}
```